# Trying to understand SmartCRTL results: Normed value less than the worst value?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, smart

Please see the below output of `smartctl` for external hard drive. For attribute: `Offline_Uncorrectable`, the current normed-value is less that the worst value.

How is it possible? **It should be always more than or equal to the worst value. Isn't it?** (since, lower values indicate closer to threshold)

Also are the 12 errors, matter of concern?

```
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-6.6.7-200.fc39.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Elements / My Passport (USB, AF)
Device Model:     WDC WD10JMVW-11AJGS0
Serial Number:    WD-WXP1EA2FNZ95
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 6ae1f0806
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5563
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Dec 31 22:41:20 2023 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM level is:     128 (minimum power consumption without standby)
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: Incomplete response, ATA output registers missing
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
Warning: This result is based on an Attribute check.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (16800) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 188) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   200   200   051    -    27
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS--K   175   172   021    -    2241
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   099   099   000    -    1043
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   200   200   140    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         -OSR-K   200   200   000    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   099   099   000    -    1107
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    741
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    423
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   195   195   000    -    15743
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   098   091   000    -    49
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   253   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   ---R--   200   200   000    -    0
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      6  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa0-0xa7  GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xb6  GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xb7       GPL,SL  VS      38  Device vendor specific log
0xbd       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc0       GPL,SL  VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL     VS      93  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (6 sectors)
Device Error Count: 12
    CR     = Command Register
    FEATR  = Features Register
    COUNT  = Count (was: Sector Count) Register
    LBA_48 = Upper bytes of LBA High/Mid/Low Registers ]  ATA-8
    LH     = LBA High (was: Cylinder High) Register    ]   LBA
    LM     = LBA Mid (was: Cylinder Low) Register      ] Register
    LL     = LBA Low (was: Sector Number) Register     ]
    DV     = Device (was: Device/Head) Register
    DC     = Device Control Register
    ER     = Error register
    ST     = Status register
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 12 [11] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 533 hours (22 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 60 29 20 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00602920 = 6301984

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 29 20 40 00     00:00:23.890  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 42 c9 23 b0 40 00     00:00:23.886  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 fb 20 40 00     00:00:23.879  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 42 c9 23 c8 40 00     00:00:23.875  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 14 38 40 00     00:00:23.867  READ DMA EXT

Error 11 [10] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 172 hours (7 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 0e 04 c3 60 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x0e04c360 = 235193184

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0e 04 c3 60 40 00     00:08:52.118  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 1f f7 90 40 00     00:08:52.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 1e b3 50 40 00     00:08:52.103  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 1e b3 50 40 00     00:08:52.102  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 2e 98 40 00     00:08:52.083  READ DMA EXT

Error 10 [9] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 172 hours (7 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 63 2e 98 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00632e98 = 6499992

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 2e 98 40 00     00:08:47.956  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 1d 50 eb 18 40 00     00:08:47.956  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 61 52 d0 40 00     00:08:47.955  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 1d 50 eb 60 40 00     00:08:47.955  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 15 0a 4b 70 40 00     00:08:47.942  READ DMA EXT

Error 9 [8] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 172 hours (7 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 63 4a 20 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00634a20 = 6507040

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 4a 20 40 00     00:08:43.334  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 4a 18 40 00     00:08:43.333  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 4a 10 40 00     00:08:43.333  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 4a 08 40 00     00:08:43.332  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 9e 90 40 00     00:08:43.320  READ DMA EXT

Error 8 [7] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 172 hours (7 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 61 56 80 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00615680 = 6379136

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 61 56 80 40 00     00:08:15.374  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 61 56 98 40 00     00:08:15.362  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c a9 8c d0 40 00     00:08:15.361  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 6e a8 40 00     00:08:15.361  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 6e a0 40 00     00:08:15.360  READ DMA EXT

Error 7 [6] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 172 hours (7 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 28 67 fd 18 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x2867fd18 = 677903640

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 28 67 fd 18 40 00     00:08:08.803  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 48 e8 40 00     00:08:08.802  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 28 65 dd 88 40 00     00:08:08.784  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 48 c8 40 00     00:08:08.783  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0f 97 03 58 40 00     00:08:08.782  READ DMA EXT

Error 6 [5] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 172 hours (7 days + 4 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 61 99 50 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00619950 = 6396240

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 61 99 50 40 00     00:08:03.746  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 64 08 70 40 00     00:08:03.734  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0f 89 e7 d8 40 00     00:08:03.719  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 61 e6 48 40 00     00:08:03.718  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 61 e6 40 40 00     00:08:03.715  READ DMA EXT

Error 5 [4] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 164 hours (6 days + 20 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  04 -- 51 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  e1 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:18.823  IDLE IMMEDIATE
  ec 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     00:00:18.823  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 25 00 40 00     00:00:09.320  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 80 00 00 0c 0d 18 00 40 00     00:00:09.303  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c 0d 18 18 40 00     00:00:09.302  READ DMA EXT

Error 4 [3] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 135 hours (5 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 60 08 30 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600830 = 6293552

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 08 30 40 00     00:00:04.383  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0f 94 7c 90 40 00     00:00:04.383  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 b7 b8 40 00     00:00:04.381  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 b5 e0 40 00     00:00:04.363  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 01 00 00 0f 94 7c 88 40 00     00:00:04.362  READ DMA EXT

Error 3 [2] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 131 hours (5 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 00 60 09 40 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00600940 = 6293824

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 09 40 40 00     01:33:36.857  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 84 48 40 00     01:33:33.715  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 63 84 40 40 00     01:33:32.592  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c a8 49 b0 40 00     01:33:32.589  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c a8 49 a8 40 00     01:33:32.574  READ DMA EXT

Error 2 [1] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 129 hours (5 days + 9 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 08 00 00 07 b6 60 48 40 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x07b66048 = 129392712

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 07 b6 60 48 40 00     00:47:36.995  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c 16 5f 08 40 00     00:47:36.994  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 0c 16 5f 08 40 00     00:47:35.743  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 06 7e 4a 48 40 00     00:47:34.327  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 58 70 40 00     00:47:34.317  READ DMA EXT

Error 1 [0] occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 128 hours (5 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER -- ST COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC
  -- -- -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --
  40 -- 51 00 28 00 00 04 80 1b 88 40 00  Error: UNC 40 sectors at LBA = 0x04801b88 = 75504520

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FEATR COUNT  LBA_48  LH LM LL DV DC  Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- == -- == -- == == == -- -- -- -- --  ---------------  --------------------
  25 00 00 00 28 00 00 04 80 1b 78 40 00     00:02:58.299  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 20 00 00 04 78 d7 d0 40 00     00:02:58.288  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 1f 40 40 00     00:02:58.268  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 60 1f 08 40 00     00:02:58.247  READ DMA EXT
  25 00 00 00 08 00 00 1e ed 91 d8 40 00     00:02:58.229  READ DMA EXT

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1107         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       837         -
# 3  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%       795         -
# 4  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%       377         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       258 (0x0102)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    48 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     21/53 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     20/56 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Vendor specific:
03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         1 minute
Temperature Logging Interval:        1 minute
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/60 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:           -41/85 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (81)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  82    2023-12-31 20:34    50  *******************************
  83    2023-12-31 20:35    51  ********************************
 ...    ..( 11 skipped).    ..  ********************************
  95    2023-12-31 20:47    51  ********************************
  96    2023-12-31 20:48    52  *********************************
 ...    ..( 16 skipped).    ..  *********************************
 113    2023-12-31 21:05    52  *********************************
 114    2023-12-31 21:06    53  **********************************
 ...    ..( 10 skipped).    ..  **********************************
 125    2023-12-31 21:17    53  **********************************
 126    2023-12-31 21:18    52  *********************************
 127    2023-12-31 21:19    52  *********************************
   0    2023-12-31 21:20    51  ********************************
   1    2023-12-31 21:21    50  *******************************
   2    2023-12-31 21:22    49  ******************************
   3    2023-12-31 21:23    48  *****************************
   4    2023-12-31 21:24    48  *****************************
   5    2023-12-31 21:25    48  *****************************
   6    2023-12-31 21:26    47  ****************************
 ...    ..( 30 skipped).    ..  ****************************
  37    2023-12-31 21:57    47  ****************************
  38    2023-12-31 21:58    48  *****************************
 ...    ..( 42 skipped).    ..  *****************************
  81    2023-12-31 22:41    48  *****************************

SCT Error Recovery Control command not supported

Device Statistics (GP/SMART Log 0x04) not supported

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0002  2            0  R_ERR response for data FIS
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0005  2            0  R_ERR response for non-data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS
0x0008  2            0  Device-to-host non-data FIS retries
0x0009  2            1  Transition from drive PhyRdy to drive PhyNRdy
0x000a  2            1  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x000b  2            0  CRC errors within host-to-device FIS
0x000f  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS, CRC
0x0012  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS, CRC
0x8000  4        11541  Vendor specific
```

Answer (score 1):

SMART attribute 198 which is displayed in your output as
"Offline_Uncorrectable" is otherwise known as
[Uncorrectable Sector Count](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9134?ckattempt=1).

The Value and Worst items are a bit meaningless here, and you should
rather look at its raw value. As the value is zero, you could
rest assured that your disk has no uncorrectable sector errors
and is in good shape.

Comment: Also are the 12 errors, matter of concern?

Comment: All critical SMART attributes are very good. The "READ DMA EXT" error can be many things, my search shows that it may be related to power or voltage failures, so perhaps it's worthwhile to verify the PSU, or add a UPS or at least a surge-protector. To be sure you could run a BIOS/UEFI disk/SMART test (if it exists in your BIOS/UEFI).